# failed loading configuration file main/conf.ts Error code: 105

Tags: typescript, protractor

Getting the error message while try to run protractor test using **protractor main/conf.ts**

```
[15:01:30] E/configParser - Error: password should be a string
at Object.ensure (C:\Repos\...\node_modules\tiny-types\lib\ensure.js:36:15)
at new Authenticator (C:\Repos\...\node_modules\authenticator-browser-extension\lib\Authenticator.js:23:22)
at Function.Authenticator.for (C:\Repos\...\node_modules\authenticator-browser-extension\lib\Authenticator.js:36:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Repos\...\main\conf.ts:30:26)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
```

[15:01:30] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[15:01:30] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file main/conf.ts
[15:01:30] **E/configParser - Error: password should be a string**
at Object.ensure (C:\Repos...\node_modules\tiny-types\lib\ensure.js:36:15)
at new Authenticator (C:\Repos...\node_modules\authenticator-browser-extension\lib\Authenticator.js:23:22)
at Function.Authenticator.for (C:\Repos...\node_modules\authenticator-browser-extension\lib\Authenticator.js:36:16)
at Object. (C:\Repos...\main\conf.ts:30:26)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

**.env file:**
`username=abc@myemail.com

password=abc@myemail.com

baseUrl=https://mywebsite.com

sql_server = testdb.database.windows.net

sql_database = test-tst-sqldb

db_password = testpassword`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use double quotes in your password. So instead of password=abc@myemail.com use

```
password "abc@myemail.com"
```